# List comprehension version of "extend"

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a 1-liner equivalent (using list comprehension) for the following:

```
a = []
for i in range(6):
    a.extend(((-i,i,0,2),(-i-1,i,0,6)))
a = tuple(a)
```

I was thinking something like

```
tuple(((-i,i,0,2),(-i-1,i,0,6)) for i in range(6))
```

but this gives:

```
(((0, 0, 0, 2), (-1, 0, 0, 6)),
 ((-1, 1, 0, 2), (-2, 1, 0, 6)),
 ((-2, 2, 0, 2), (-3, 2, 0, 6)),
 ((-3, 3, 0, 2), (-4, 3, 0, 6)),
 ((-4, 4, 0, 2), (-5, 4, 0, 6)),
 ((-5, 5, 0, 2), (-6, 5, 0, 6)))
```

which is not what I want.

**Desired output**

```
((0, 0, 0, 2),
 (-1, 0, 0, 6),
 (-1, 1, 0, 2),
 (-2, 1, 0, 6),
 (-2, 2, 0, 2),
 (-3, 2, 0, 6),
 (-3, 3, 0, 2),
 (-4, 3, 0, 6),
 (-4, 4, 0, 2),
 (-5, 4, 0, 6),
 (-5, 5, 0, 2),
 (-6, 5, 0, 6))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension.

```
>>> [t for i in range(6) for t in ((-i,i,0,2), (-i-1,i,0,6))]
>>> 
[(0, 0, 0, 2),
 (-1, 0, 0, 6),
 (-1, 1, 0, 2),
 (-2, 1, 0, 6),
 (-2, 2, 0, 2),
 (-3, 2, 0, 6),
 (-3, 3, 0, 2),
 (-4, 3, 0, 6),
 (-4, 4, 0, 2),
 (-5, 4, 0, 6),
 (-5, 5, 0, 2),
 (-6, 5, 0, 6)]
```

It reads like this

```
[what I want (t) | for loops as if writing non-listcomp code]
```

and is thus equivalent to

```
result = []
for i in range(6):
    for t in ((-i,i,0,2), (-i-1,i,0,6)):
        result.append(t)
```